# I want to run a python script that is on my computer and have it run when a button on flask server is pushed

Tags: python, flask, macros

Ultimately, im trying to make a macro base for my pc. I have flask installed and have an html made up for it. In the html page referenced at /, I want the button to just run a python script running on the same machine as the flask server is. Im a beginner with flask and but for now i just want flask to run a script from my computer and ill branch off making macros from there. Skeleton code would be extremely helpful and how it should be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can complete this by coming back to the server with a request and running the script.
I suggest using a framework for creating software instead of flask if you are only using this on your local device.

```
import os
@app.route("/")
def home():
  return "<button onclick=\"$.get('runScript', function(data, status){alert('Done!');});\">Run</button><script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>" # Return button
@app.route("/runScript")
def runScript():
  os.system("python3 script.py")
  return("Done!")
```

You can try this out at https://replit.com/@UCYT5040/testt.

Comment: Thanks for this. So from what im reading, the root of the flask page will display a button and it will alter the browser once its clicked? Then the script is located in /runScript with the python script?

Comment: Yep! Basically we are going back to the server with Ajax.

Comment: Awesome. I incorporated this logic to what im making and it works well!

Comment: Can you mark the as the correct answer if it helped you or answered your question?